# Mysql WHERE X matches both Y AND Z

Tags: mysql, select, join, tags

I have 3 tables for storing images, tags and a link between the two. The structure is like this:

Table - photos

```
pid     name
--------------
1       image1
2       image2
3       image3
4       image4
```

Table - tags

```
tagID   tagName
---------------
1       red
2       blue
3       yellow
4       green
```

Table - photo_tag_bridge

```
pid     tagID
-------------
1       1
2       1
3       1
1       2
1       3
```

I want to create a SELECT statement to retrieve only the rows from 'photos' which match multiple 'tagID's. I've currently got this to try and bring back just image1 as it matches tagID 1 and 2

```
SELECT photos.pid
, photo_tag_bridge.pid, photo_tag_bridge.tagID
, tags.tagID 
FROM photos
, photo_tag_bridge
, tags 
where photos.pid = photo_tag_bridge.pid 
AND photo_tag_bridge.tagID = 1 
AND photo_tag_bridge.tagID = 2 
GROUP BY photos.pid
```

This doesn't bring anything back and it seems i may need to use an INNER JOIN?

Comment: select x.* from x where n in ('a','b') group by x.i having count (distinct n) =2... or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 obvious solutions. One is to join to 2 instances of photo_tag_bridge (and two instances of tags *if you were actually using any data from this table*):

```
SELECT photos.pid
FROM photos
, photo_tag_bridge ptb_a
, photo_tag_bridge ptb_b
WHERE photos.pid = ptb_a.pid 
AND photos.pid = ptb_b.pid 
AND ptb_a.tagID = 1 
AND ptb_b.tagID = 2
```

Or you do an aggregate matching the DISTINCT count to the number of required matches (which is handy to match, for example, any 2 of 3 tags):

```
SELECT photos.pid
FROM photos
, photo_tag_bridge ptb
WHERE photos.pid = ptb_a.pid 
AND photos.pid = bptb_b.pid 
AND ptb.tagID IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY photos.pid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ptb.tagID)=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

As for my understanding, you need to get photo id which has multiple tags.

```
 create table #photo(id int,name varchar(10))
 create table #phototag(pid int,tgid int)
 create table #tag(id int,name varchar(10))

 select p.id,p.name from #photo p inner join #phototag pt on pt.pid=p.id group by p.id,p.name having count(*)>1
```